# Tkinter - After Second Button Click, Change Button Function to Close Window

Tags: python, tkinter, label, tkinter-entry, tkinter-button

I am trying to figure out a way to change a button's text and functionality after I have clicked the `Submit` button a second time. In the below instance, I am trying to:

**1)** Change the button's text from `Submit` to `Close` after I have entered in the username/password fields for `SecondName` and have clicked `Submit`

**2)** Use the `Close()` function to close the window.

I have attempted to accomplish these two processes by using an `if/else` statement.

**Tkinter Code**

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

user_var = tk.StringVar()
pass_var = tk.StringVar()
entries = {}


def Submit():
    user = user_var.get()
    passw = pass_var.get()
    label_text = user_label["text"]
    char = label_text.split()[0]

    entries[char] = (user, passw)
    if char == "FirstName":
        user_label["text"] = "SecondName " + user_label["text"].split()[1]
        pass_label["text"] = "SecondName " + pass_label["text"].split()[1]
    user_var.set("")
    pass_var.set("")
    print(entries)


def Close():
    root.quit()

user_label = tk.Label(root, text="FirstName Username", width=21)
user_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=user_var)

pass_label = tk.Label(root, text="FirstName Password", width=21)
pass_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=pass_var, show="•")

if user_entry["text"] == "SecondName":
    sub_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Close", command=Close)
else:
    sub_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=Submit)

sub_btn.grid(row=2, column=0)

user_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
user_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

pass_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
pass_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

**Current Result**

[image]

**Expected Result**

[image]

Comment: When you split `user_label["text"]` it's going to return a list of two values. You're trying to get the index of a third value.

Comment: Put this in line 23 sub_btn.configure(text='Close')

Comment: After you got that in line 23. You need to do  two case statement; one for submit and one for close. You don't need to write another function. Just one function will all  reduced code sizes.

Comment: Consider looking at the answers below to close this question

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is the misunderstanding of how event driven programming works. The following line of code runs ONLY when the tkinter window is initially drawn.

```
if user_entry["text"] == "SecondName":
    sub_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Close", command=Close)
else:
    sub_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=Submit)
```

Which means `user_entry["text"]` is never `"SecondName"`. Furthermore, `user_entry["text"]` does not do what you expect it to be doing, it returns the `name` of the `textvariable` option and not the contents of the entry widget, what you need to do is change your function to use `elif`:

```
def Submit():
    user = user_var.get()
    passw = pass_var.get()
    label_text = user_label["text"]
    char = label_text.split()[0]

    entries[char] = (user, passw)
    if char == "FirstName":
        user_label["text"] = "SecondName " + user_label["text"].split()[1]
        pass_label["text"] = "SecondName " + pass_label["text"].split()[1]
    elif char == "SecondName":
        sub_btn.config(text='Close', command=Close) # Change button if `char` is "SecondName" only

    user_var.set("")
    pass_var.set("")
    print(entries)
```

Side Note: To get the value inside the entry widget, you can use `user_entry.get()` or `user_var.get()`